# Go: require module from local folder with replace

Tags: go

I have:

- **a module** (`/Users/collimarco/Sites/pushpad-go`)
- **a demo application** that uses that module (`/Users/collimarco/Sites/pushpad-example-app/go`)

They are in two separate folders, in different paths.

I need to follow this structure, because the same convention is used for many other languages.

This is **the module**:

```golang
// /Users/collimarco/Sites/pushpad-go/go.mod

module github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go

go 1.19
```

This is **the demo application** that needs to use that module:

```golang
// /Users/collimarco/Sites/pushpad-example-app/go/go.mod

module pushpad-go-example

go 1.19

replace "github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go" v0.0.0 => "/Users/collimarco/Sites/pushpad-go"
```

```golang
// /Users/collimarco/Sites/pushpad-example-app/go/main.go

package main

import (
  "github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go/pushpad"
)

func main() {
  n := pushpad.Notification { Body: "Example notification" }
  n.Broadcast()
}
```

I read different blog posts and that seems the correct approach. However I get this error:

```
$ go run .
main.go:4:3: no required module provides package github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go/pushpad; to add it:
    go get github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go/pushpad
```

I don't want to download the module from an online repository, as the error suggests: I just want to import the code from the local folder. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem here is that you're importing `github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go/pushpad`; the trailing `/pushpad` is a problem because that is not part of the repository path. So the code in your `main.go` should have:

```golang
import (
  "github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go"
)
```

You still need a require directive for the module as well. If you go get it at version v0.0.0, the replace directive will retrieve it from your local folder. So:

```
go get github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go@0.0.0
```

should add this to your go.mod:

```
require (
    github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go v0.0.0
)
```

Also, quotes are not necessary in your replace directive. It should be:

```
replace github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go v0.0.0 => /Users/collimarco/Sites/pushpad-go
```

Another way of doing this, rather than editing your `go.mod` file manually, is to use `go mod edit -replace` like so:

```
go mod edit -replace github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go=/Users/collimarco/Sites/pushpad-go
```

That should "do the right thing".

Comment: Thank you! Now I get `main.go:4:3: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go/pushpad (imported by pushpad-go-example); to add: go get pushpad-go-example`. So I run `go get pushpad-go-example` and I get this error: `ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to commit every change to a Git repo before using the module in the demo application? Is there any way, for development, to use the local files in the *working directory* (without having to commit every change)?

Comment: @collimarco, the local `replace` will use the local files. What makes you think you need to push every change in order to use local files?

Comment: @JimB It's the fact that when I type `go get pushpad-go-example`, I get this error: `go: github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go/pushpad@v0.0.0: reading github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go/pushpad/go.mod at revision pushpad/v0.0.0: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/collimarco/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/a8n8946ndshka87g: exit status 128: ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: @collimarco If the package doesn’t yet exist to get a real version, add the dependency manually, `go mod edit -require` or write it in the go.mod directly. You might also want to look at [go workspaces](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces)

Comment: @JimB I added the `require` and `replace` rules exactly as described in this answer. Isn't that enough?

Comment: 1. I have configured the go.mod as described in this answer 2. If I type `go run .` in the demo application Go says: `missing go.sum entry [...] to add: go get pushpad-go-example` 3. I follow the instructions and I type that command (`go get pushpad-go-example`), however I get this error: `go: github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go/pushpad@v0.0.0: reading github.com/pushpad/pushpad-go/pushpad/go.mod at revision pushpad/v0.0.0: unknown revision pushpad/v0.0.0`. It seems that Go is still trying to get the code from the online repo, not from the local folder... Why?

Comment: @collimarco: The described situation works correctly. Are you certain you are editing the correct `go.mod`? Is the `pushpad` source really in a subdirectory called `pushpad`?

Comment: @collimarco I've revised my answer above. You had an additional problem with the import path itself. Also, in the future using `go mod edit -replace` would be easier.